# Navigation in Nativescript / Angular - Backfunction in shared module?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a project, where I want to provide a back button for navigation in a sidedrawer.
I found a Nativescript project of the nativescript team where they have a standard project structure with some usabilities I try to implement:

[Nativescript - Team project](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng/)

Here they have back-funtions declared in every component, where they offer the back function, but is there a way to offer this "globaly" e.g. in a sidedrawer?

also: Is it recommended to use lazyloading in such a small project? (I didn't split my routing in so many modules as they did but in their case it is also related to the implemented `loadchildren` property - am I right?)

last question: I am not able to use the standard `routerExtensions.back()` function (canGoBack, backToPreviousPage, etc. is not working aswell) but I found a workaround:

`this.routerExt.navigate([this.route.parent.pathFromRoot]);`
this works for navigating backwards but I can't use it in a Sidedrawer...

If you have any suggestions, let me know.
Cheers

Comment: You said you were not able to use the "routerExtensions.back()" can you share the error code? It should work with that. Have you injected it in your constructor?

Comment: There was no specific Error, just nothing happened when clicking the backbutton. I use a workaround now, where I store my last used Urls in an array and use these Urls then to navigate to when clicking back.